# How find maximum time with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max, partition-by

I've the following table (my_data):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#tmp_time](
    [seq_id] int NULL,
    [seq_wf] int NULL,
    [update_ts] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tmp_time] ([seq_id],[seq_wf],[update_ts]) VALUES (230000,23,'20220319 10:02:33')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tmp_time] ([seq_id],[seq_wf],[update_ts]) VALUES (230001,23,'20220319 10:28:33')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tmp_time] ([seq_id],[seq_wf],[update_ts]) VALUES (230002,23,'20220319 10:37:33')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tmp_time] ([seq_id],[seq_wf],[update_ts]) VALUES (230000,23,'20220319 18:02:33')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tmp_time] ([seq_id],[seq_wf],[update_ts]) VALUES (230001,23,'20220319 19:28:33')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tmp_time] ([seq_id],[seq_wf],[update_ts]) VALUES (230002,23,'20220319 18:37:33')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tmp_time] ([seq_id],[seq_wf],[update_ts]) VALUES (230000,23,'20220320 20:02:33')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tmp_time] ([seq_id],[seq_wf],[update_ts]) VALUES (230001,23,'20220320 20:28:33')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#tmp_time] ([seq_id],[seq_wf],[update_ts]) VALUES (230002,23,'20220321 21:37:33')
```

I would like to get the result with below values

```
230002,23,'20220319 10:37:33'
230001,23,'20220319 19:28:33'
230002,23,'20220321 21:37:33'
```

I use:

```
select distinct [seq_id]
    , max([update_ts]) over (partition by [seq_id]) max_time
from [dbo].[#tmp_time]
```

How can I fix the request?

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo in the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT 
    [seq_id], [seq_wf], MAX([update_ts]) [update_ts]
FROM [dbo].[#tmp_time] 
GROUP BY [seq_id], [seq_wf]
```

Comment: A good answer contains an explanation as well as working code.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT [seq_id],[seq_wf],MAX([update_ts])
FROM [dbo].[#tmp_time] 
GROUP BY [seq_id],[seq_wf]
```

Comment: Seems identical to the existing answer?

Comment: A good answer contains an explanation as well as working code.